# Regex - lazy match first pattern occurrence, but no subsequent matching patterns

Tags: regex

I need to return the first percentage, and only the first percentage, from each row in a file.

1. Each row may have one or two, but not more than two, percentages.
2. There may or may not be other numbers in the line, such as a dollar amount.
3. The percentage may appear anywhere in the line.

Ex:

```
Profits in California were down 10.00% to $100.00, a decrease from 22.6% the prior year.
Profits in New York increased by 0.9%.
Profits in Texas were up 1.58% an increase from last year's 0.58%.
```

I can write a regex to capture all occurrences:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+[%]+?
```

https://regex101.com/r/owZaGE/1

The other SO questions I've perused only address this issue when the pattern is at the front of the line or [always preceded by a particular set of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match)

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine is similar to you except I allowed numbers like 30% (without decimal points)

```
\d+(\.\d+)?%
```

I don't know what language you are using, but in python for getting the first occurrence you can use `re.search()`

Here is an example:

```
import re

pattern = r'\d+(\.\d+)?%'
string = 'Profits in California were down 10.00% to $100.00, a decrease from 22.6% the prior year.'

print(re.search(pattern, string).group())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/^.*?((?:\d+\.)?\d+%)/gm
```

works with a multiline flag, no negative lookbehind (some engines don't support non-fixed width lookbehinds). Your match will be in the capture group.

Comment: You can get rid of the false negative by combining a negative lookahead with `.`: [`^(?:(?!\d+%).)*?((?:\d+\.)?\d+%)`](https://regex101.com/r/boyL7I/1/)

Comment: Or simply use `.*?` instead of `[^%]*?` since it's non-greedy

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve using a [negative lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925305/regex-negative-look-behind-anywhere-on-line):

```
(?<!%.*?)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+[%]+?)
```

Comment: The `[%]+` can just be `%`. It seems unlikely that you'd need to match more than 1 consecutive percent sign.